# Diagram for applications databases dependencies and interactions

Tags: diagram

I'm looking for a diagram type that lets me model applications, databases and their dependencies. Does such an diagram exist, or do people just use UML or something similar?

Comment: What's wrong with UML?  Why wouldn't that be your first choice?

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't really know much UML. Is it a good choice for this particular use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML.

Component Diagram and Deployment Diagram.

http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/componentDiagram.htm

http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3291941/Deployment-Diagram-in-UML.htm